# HttpURLConnection : How does client and server keep in sync

Tags: java, servlets, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection and I have a problem understanding on how client and server sync. Assume simple download file example. This example is copied somewhere from web. I am only using the code to state the standard process.

Servlet code is like:

```
   response.setContentType(mimeType);
   response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

   String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
   String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
   response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // obtains response's output stream
   OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    //write to stream
    //close the stream
```

And Client code is like :

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
    String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
    int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();
    //parse content-disposition
    ....
    InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
    String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

    // opens an output stream to save into file
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);
    //write to stream
    //close stream
} else {
    //if non Ok status
}
```

My first question is : Is `httConn.getResponseCode()` a blocking call that waits for the servlet to finish processing? Otherwise, if error comes or servlet call `response.sendError()`, when you are inside `if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {`, what will happen.

Second Question : is an extension of first question. If responseCode is not blocking, then when i am accessing disposition, contentType, cotentLength, how am i sure that they are already set.

Third Question. If `httConn.getResponseCode()` is blocking. So if I want to send send some message to the client, how correct is to send it to the client in response headers like : `resposnse.setHeader("my-message", "some message I want to send");` rather than using `response.getWriter()` to write to the stream. So that I am sure client will definitely read that.

Fourth Question : If I am writing two objects to streams on servlet, how will client distinguish or can it distinguish? Suppose I am writing a class object using `response.getObjectOutputStream()` and then I may be writing some string using writer or may be write a file after that. Can client distinguish these different items coming in stream or do I have to use multiple request. One request per object or file or String to be read from stream.

Comment: Your questions aren't about servlets, but about the HTTP protocol which they use. I suggest reading about the the basics of HTTP before getting into servlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, as [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29) indicates

> Gets the status code from an HTTP response message. For example, in the case of the following status lines:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
> HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
> ```
>
> It will return 200 and 401 respectively. Returns -1 if no code can be discerned from the response (i.e., the response is not valid HTTP).

2. NA
3. You can use headers if you want, but headers are limited to text only and limited in length (AFAIR). The response body is usually used to contain... the response body. Whereas headers are typically used for metadata.
4. server and client have to agree on a protocol. If the protocol is that a response contains two objects, then the client should read two objects. I would not do that though. You'd better send a unique container object rather than 2 in sequence. HTTP can be used to transport anything, but a JSON or XML document is usually used to transport structured data.

Comment: regarding (4) AFAIK the content type of the body is declared in as a header `Content-Type`, right?

Comment: Yes. The Java API allows setting/getting some common standard headers (like content length, content type) using dedicated methods rather than a generic seHeader/getHeader method.